# Show small numbers as zero

Tags: python, pandas

I'm very often fooled by very small float values in pandas which are "effectively zero".

For example, it's hard to see at first glance what's going on with the following `Series`:

```
are_they_zero
a   -5.960464e-08 # This number is small
b   -2.384186e+07 # This one isn't
c    2.384186e-07
d   -5.960464e+08
e    8.940697e-08
```

Is there a way to tell pandas to show numbers like `5.960464e-08` as `0`?

(Clearly it would depend on the application as to whether this is a good idea or not, but assume that, in my case, it is.)

Comment: Assuming you are using ipython, there is the `%precision` magic

Comment: @JohnE I am: can you expand this into an answer and give an example?

Comment: Actually, I was just playing around with it and may not be that useful with pandas.  It will only work if you print an individual value, but not when you print several values (series, array, dataframe).  Anyway, just type `?precision` at the prompt to see more about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`set_option`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.set_option.html#pandas.set_option) with `'display.chop_threshold'` to handle this:

```
In [20]:
pd.set_option('display.chop_threshold', 0.001)
df

Out[20]:
   are_they_zero
a              0
b  -2.384186e+07
c              0
d  -5.960464e+08
e              0
```

Comment: No worries, I wasn't sure if this existed or not so I thought I'd look this up and it did exist and did what you wanted

Answer (score 0):

You could make usage of [build in `round()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round) as this appears to be a float.

As an alternative, trying a check like (pseudo)

```
if c <  2.3e-05:
    c = 0
```